# IPC with over 100 different methods - viable way to maintain readability

Tags: c#, ipc

I have a system with 2 different processes. Process 1 starts process 2 and sets up an `AnonymousPipe` between the 2. Process 1 needs to run some code and needs to interact with process 2 to get info and commit changes. Process 2 runs on Python with references to C# code (since I'm more familiar with C#) so process 2 has a while(true) loop to listen to process 1.

Process 2 has 3 classes that are "services" to underlying code. A simplified example:

```
// Runs under Process 2 (Python)
public class LibraryManager
{
   public string GetCategory(string something) // Step 3.1
   {
       return something;
   } 
}

// Runs under Process 2 (Python)
public class Agent
{
    public void Run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            // pipe is the anonymouspipe wrapped in an easy to handle class
            var function = pipe.Read<Command>(); // Step 2 - waits here for a write, halts code but this is ok for me
            switch (function)
            {
                case Command.LibraryManager_Category:
                    pipe.Write(LibraryManager.GetCategory("something"); // Step 3
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
        }
    }
}

// Runs under Process 1 (C#)
public class LibraryManagerService
{
    public string GetCategory()
    {
        CodesysEngine.Pipe.Write(Command.LibraryManager_Category); // Step 1
        return CodesysEngine.Pipe.Read<string>(); // Step 4 - this halts the code until the Agent does his write, this is ok for me
    }
}
```

I'm doing this communication now via an `enum` `Command`. This works. If I need to send data to Process 2 I can just write 2 things and bases on the `Command` change the type I read. (I've done some coding under the hood to be able to do this.)

What I'm not 100% satisfied with is the `Command` I use to tell the `Agent` which part of code to execute. This example only has 1 method but I see this growing to over 100 which will make it not very readable as it will be a `switch` with over 100 `case`es. I was thinking of splitting the `enum` per service and have a "master" `enum` with the 3 services as a divider. (First send which service, then send which method, then send any arguments if needed.)

Is there a more standardized way of doing what I want to achieve cause I have the feeling this can get pretty fast too big to handle?